# On a matrix algorithm involving rank-one projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits-and-convergence, fixed-point-theorems, matrix-equations

Let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be a set of $n$-dimensional real vectors spanning $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $p\in [0,1]$ be a rational number and consider the iteration
\begin{equation}
X_{k+1}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{X_k^{p}v_i v_i^\top X_k^{p}}{v_i^\top X_k^{2p}v_i},\quad X_0=\frac{1}{n}I_n\qquad (\star)
\end{equation}
(Given a positive semi-definite matrix $Y$, $Y^p$, $p\in\mathbb{Q},\ p\in (0,1)$, denotes the principal matrix $p$-th root of $Y$).
If we denote by $\Pi_y:=\frac{y y^\top}{y^\top y}$ the orthogonal projection onto $\mathrm{span}\{y\}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then ($\star$) can be seen as an **arithmetic mean of rank-one orthogonal projections** each one projecting onto $\mathrm{span}\{X_k^p v_i\}$, namely
\begin{equation}
X_{k+1}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \Pi_{X_k^p v_i},\quad X_0=\frac{1}{n}I_n\qquad (\star\star)
\end{equation}
Notice that ($\star$) sends positive definite matrices to positive definite matrices and is trace-preserving (namely its trace is always 1).

First, I would like to know if similar algorithms have been studied somewhere in the literature. In particular, I would be interested in the convergence properties of ($\star$). Note that, since ($\star$) maps trace-one positive definite matrices to trace-one positive definite matrices and is continuous, by Browuer's fixed point theorem it admits (at least) one fixed point. However, what about uniqueness and attractivity of the fixed point?

I list below other (perhaps naïve) considerations and some further comments on the algorithm ($\star$).

1. For $p=0$, the iteration clearly converges in one step to the (positive definite) arithmetic mean of the set of projections $\{\Pi_{v_i}\}_{i=1}^N$.
2. For $p=1$, extensive simulations seem to suggest that the algorithm converges to a rank-one orthogonal projection (except when we pick a set of orthogonal vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^N$, in which case the iteration stays fixed at $\frac{1}{n}I_n$).
3. For $0<p<1$, simulations seem to suggest that the algorithm converges to a positive definite matrix and the lower the value of $p$ the closer is the latter matrix to the arithmetic mean of $\{\Pi_{v_i}\}_{i=1}^N$.

Relying on the above considerations and on numerical evidences, my conjecture is that for $p<1$ there is a kind of "antagonistic action" of the matrix $p$-th root which pushes the iteration towards the the arithmetic mean of $\{\Pi_{v_i}\}_{i=1}^N$, while for $p=1$ this action disappears and the algorithm converges to an orthogonal rank-1 projection. Furthermore, my guess is that, if I will be able to prove convergence for the case $p=1$, then by a sort of continuity argument on the parameter $p$, I will also be able to prove convergence for $0<p<1$.

I've been at this problem for some time, with no further progress. Thus I really appreciate to hear your opinions/comments/criticisms. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks like the iteration has been derived by trying to solve $\nabla \Phi=0$; could you write down the original problem? We studied several such iterations previously, maybe one of them might be helpful to you, e.g., please have a look at: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.4812v2.pdf

Comment: @Suvrit: I've read your paper and I found it very interesting! Moreover, the iteration (3.8) seems to be the “regularized” version of mine! Hence, I wonder if I can use an argument similar to that used in Sec 3.1 to prove convergence of my iteration for $p=1/2$ (perhaps, replacing $I$ by $\varepsilon I$ and letting $\varepsilon\to 0$?). I think that one issue is that Lemma 3 doesn't hold anymore and this implies that my iteration can tend to a singular matrix (rank-1 projection, actually). However, I know that my iteration always admits a positive-definite fixed point and maybe this can help.

Comment: Did you check if an argument similar to that for (3.10) works out in your case?

Comment: @Suvrit: I had a look at (3.10), although I haven’t gone through the proof yet. However, it seems to me a bit different to my iteration (due to the fact that in (3.10) $\Gamma_p$ only appears in the “denominator”). I found (3.8) more similar to it. My guess is that starting from an “$\varepsilon I$ version” of (3.8), by using a kind of “continuity” argument for $\varepsilon\to 0$ and the additional assumption that my iteration always possesses a positive-definite fixed point, it can be proved that the iteration has a unique and globally attractive (positive-definite) fixed point.

Comment: Yes, using an $\epsilon I$ perturbation and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ in (3.8) will "work" except for the one troublesome thing of ensuring that the limit is strictly positive definite....

Comment: @Suvrit: Thank you for the comment. I agree with you, indeed I think that the thing is not that easy to prove due to the fact that the limit could be singular. Relying on numerical simulations, it seems that if the iteration admits a positive-definite fixed point (which is not always true) then this fixed point is unique and globally attractive. In any case, I think that the $\varepsilon$-perturbation argument might be used to prove (at least) *local* attractivity around a positive-definite fixed point...I will think about it in the next days...

Comment: What I meant in my first comment was: consider minimization of $$\phi(X) = \text{trace}(X) - \sum_i \log(v_i^TXv_i).$$ This is strictly convex on $X \succ 0$. Thus, if $\nabla \phi(X)=0$ has a solution, it will be unique. Using Brouwer, you claimed existence (though am not sure about it because you need to also establish a compact set within which the iteration lives)....cont'd

Comment: ...But since $\phi(X)$ goes to $+\infty$ as $X\to \infty$ or $X\to 0$, solution should exist more directly without invoking Brouwer. The tricky part is to show that the Picard iteration converges to this fixed point. But since the fixed point is unique, the chances of this Picard iteration being convergent greatly increase, and should be possible to show...

Comment: @Suvrit: Great comments, thanks! As you pointed out, the main problem is that, even if $\nabla \phi(X)=0$ admits a (unique) solution, since the Picard iteration lives in the set of trace-1 positive semi-definite matrices it can tend towards a singular matrix. (Btw, I used Brouwer’s theorem w.r.t. the aforementioned compact set). My (vague) idea is to exploit the additional fact that the $\varepsilon I$-perturbed Picard iteration always converges, and then use some kind of "exchanging limits law’’ between $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $k\to \infty$. However, to prove the last step is the main issue...

Comment: @Suvrit: Just a clarification, are you sure that $\phi(X)$ is *strictly* convex on $X>0$? For instance, assume that $X^*>0$ is a trace-1 minimum of $\phi$, then for every traceless $X_0$ s.t. $X^*+X_0> 0$, and $\sum_i v_i^\top X_0 v_i=0$, $X^*_0:=X^*+X_0>0$ is also a minimum of $\phi$.